# I need to convert h:outputtext

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich:datatable to show records on a DB and there are some columns in. Here is an example :

```
<rich:dataTable id="myTable" var="myItem" value="#{myList}">
    <rich:column width="25%">
         <h:outputText value="#{myItem.myValue}" />
    </rich:column>
...
```

Table shows the records fine. I want to show `h:outputText` value as a different value (I mean convert it). For example, reversed string or "find&replaced" result of it. There are numberConvertors, dateConvertors but couldn't find for Strings. A client side solution (like javascript,jquery) also could be plausible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *There are numberConvertors, dateConvertors but couldn't find for Strings*

Just create one yourself.

```
@FacesConverter("myStringConverter")
public class MyStringConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // Write code here which converts the model value before displaying.
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // Write code here which converts the submitted value before updating model.
        // Note that this method isn't ever used in output text.
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myItem.myValue}" converter="myStringConverter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no defaultConverters for String values.

Simplest thing you can do here is to write an alternative getMyValue()-methode.

```
<h:outputText value="#{myItem.myModifiedValue}" />
```

and in your bean sth like

```
public String getMyModifiedValue() { 
   return doSomethingwith( this.myValue );
}
```