# JSF convertNumber Pattern with whitespaces

Tags: jsf, converters

I want to display a BigInteger like this: "11111 22222 33333".

I tried the following, which does not work:

```
         <f:convertNumber pattern="#00000 00000 00000" />
```

What am I doing wrong? :-/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:convertNumber>` uses for `BigInteger` the [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) API under the covers. As you can see in its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), the blank space is not recognized as a pattern character. Valid pattern characters are `0`, `#`, `.`, `-`, etc.

You seem to want to ouptut a non-standard format. You'd need to create a custom converter for the job.

#### See also:

- [I need to convert h:outputtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305044/i-need-to-convert-houtputtext/13306758#13306758)
- [DecimalFormat is being overridden by server settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687407/decimalformat-is-being-overridden-by-server-settings/)