# <f:convertNumber/> does not recognize correct input for german currency

Tags: jsf, currency, number-formatting

I'm setting up an input field for currency in my jsf web app and have a backing bean to write the value to. However the converter `<f:convertNumber/>` doesn't seem to recognize correct input if entered by the user. The initial value can be submitted and numbers can be changed but typing in a value like
**1,00 €**
won't work. I would like to keep the formatter and also understand how to fix this problem.

> I am using `JSF 2.3.5-SP2 (Mojarra)` with `Wildfly 14.0.1` and `Java 10.0.1`

I narrowed it down to the space between the number and the currency symbol but I don't know how to make `<f:convertNumber/>` recognize a simple space as a correct input.

> After doing a little inspection the original space was identified as a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`

This is my test code:

test.xhtml

```xml
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText value="#{testModel.number}">
            <f:convertNumber type="currency" locale="de_DE" currencyCode="EUR"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{testModel.submit}"/>
        <h:messages style = "color:red;margin:8px;" />
    </h:form>
    <h:outputText value="#{testModel.number}"/>
</h:body>
```

TestModel.java

```java
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestModel {
    private BigDecimal number;

    public String submit(){
        return "#";
    }

    public BigDecimal getNumber() {
        if(number==null)number = new BigDecimal("0");
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(BigDecimal number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

When changing the number to 1,00 € by only ereasing the **0** of **0**,00 € and replacing it with a 1 I get the correct output.
[image: image of correct output]

When I replace the `&nbsp;`(non-breaking) space between the number and the '€' symbol with a simple space the messsage shows the following warning:

j_idt3:j_idt4: '0,00 €' konnte nicht als Währungswert interpretiert werden.
meaning **'0,00 €' couldn't be interpreted as a currency value.**
[image: image of wrong recognition]

Comment: Please always post version and implementation info as it is aways relevant as you can see in the answer. And _"When I replace the space between the number and the '€' symbol with a simple space"_ is unclear. What isca simple space and what was it

Comment: Sadly I don't know what kind of space is there, before replacing it. Simple space is the space you can create, when simply pressing the space bar.

Comment: Then check with a browser developer tool what sort of whitespace there is.

Comment: I addded the version an implementation info in my question above.

Comment: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ImplicitNumberConverter might be useful.

Comment: @sepphuber3 Updated the answer with a way to work around the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this using your exact code and was unable to. In fact, any `#,## €` input seems to be working just fine. Please note that `f:convertNumber` uses `DecimalFormat` under the hood - so there might be slight changes not only between JSF versions but potentially also between different versions of Java.

I ran your code with JSF 2.3 and Java 8 and it's parsing the string fine even with a space between the number and the Euro sign. Maybe you are triggering a localization bug that has been fixed in a later version ?

### Update

It seems on my specific version of Java (**Java 8, 191-b12**), JSF implementation (**2.3.3.99, Mojarra**) and localization rules the behavior is the exact opposite. If I pass a `&nbsp;` in the `inputText` the converter will refuse to parse it. Maybe this is indeed a clash between localization rules and the behavior of the component. I had to force this character into the `inputText` to trigger it though, as the browser will insert simple spaces by default.

### Working around the problem

Lucklily after some testing I discovered you can actually work around the problem by supplying a `pattern` attribute. In your specific case, the solution would be to do something like this,

```
<f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0.00 ¤" type="currency" locale="de_DE" currencyCode="EUR"/>
```

This will expect a pattern where the space between the Euro sign and the number is a simple space (`&#32`) character, instead of a `&nbsp;` which seems to be the default behavior in your environment for some reason.

Comment: In at least older java versions a space is not supported https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471141/jsf-convertnumber-pattern-with-whitespaces

Comment: Interesting... Yes, a custom converter would be my next suggestion - but it seems that's not needed at all for the above wanted behavior. It would be interesting to know what has changed and when and what exactly is causing this. If somebody has some info - do share.

Comment: What is your jsf implementation and version?

Comment: I can confirm it's working under Oracle Java 8 (191-b12) and JSF 2.3.3.99 (Mojarra)

Comment: Hmmmm 2.3.3.99? Is that the weird oracle required not-official release?

Comment: It's the release they tagged right before they handed it over to the Eclipse Foundation. I guess both the latest development branch of GlassFish uses it as well as several recent versions of Payara.

Comment: The update worked, but somehow i now get a weird malformation of the '€' showing it instead as 'â¬'. But only the first time after deployment.

Comment: @sepphuber3 Try setting `currencySymbol="€"` directly and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Somehow the second problem i mentioned of '€' turning into  'â¬' vanished. But before that even manually setting the currencySymbol='€' didn't help. Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: Hi @AdamWaldenberg , thank you for this answer... I guess I'm having a related problem since I upgraded my AWS server... maybe you can help me with this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74616683/using-fconvertnumber-type-currency-output-nbps-rather-than-ordinary-sp