# Using '<f:convertNumber type="currency" ...>' output '&nbps;' rather than 'ordinary space' between currencySymbol and value

Tags: tomcat, jsf, facelets

Recently I moved from **Tomcat 8.5 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/3.4.21**
to **Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.3.0 AWS server**, both are using Mojarra 2.2.20 implementation.

Since then, codes with <f:convertNumber/> which displays currency symbols, like:

```
  <h:outputText value="#{c.value}"   >
        <f:convertNumber  type="currency" locale="#{utilBean.user.myLocale}" />
  </h:outputText>
```

are having different behaviour on HTML pages...  in my old server it render eg.: '**$ 100,00**' (with normal space, which is what I expect), and in new server it render '**$`$&nbsp;`100,00'** (which causes me a problem when exported to excel). All other 'spaces' cases, like String Bean variables are working just fine in any page.

Which (Tomcat?) configuration should I use to force ordinary spaces?

Comment: As discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076481, introduce a `pattern` to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AdamWaldenberg in fact it solves the problem, but as I'm also dealing with locale="" hold this pattern options maybe will be complex (eg.: kind of separator or symbol order pre/post).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find which configuration resulted in that problem, but as I'm using Primefaces and my problem was only related to exported values, I was dealing with that at backend, by removing this kind of space with:
`strVal = strVal.replace("\u00a0","");` in a `postProcessor="#{exportBean.postProcessXLS}"` method (another option was set `exportValue=""` atribute in each currency column removing currency symbol).

By the way, since I upgraded to new Primefaces 12 the problem has gone because now Cells type are preserved and correctly exported.